Log Analytics Custom Logs
Hoping you can help.
I'm looking at Applocker Events and pulling them into Azure Log Analytics, currently I have this setup when simply running the Event command, but what I want to do now is to use Custom Logs in order to pull some more information in order to make life a little bit easier in creating the bypass allow rules when needed.
I've been looking at the following article which is really interesting and am trying to implement this solution https://msendpointmgr.com/2021/08/13/log-analytics-applocker-better-together/?unapproved=81275&moderation-hash=03ea4b9d585fab4de08abd910968f929#comment-81275
So I've saved the PS script:
#Obtain AppLocker Events
    $AppLockerEvents = Get-AppLockerFileInformation -EventLog -EventType Denied -Statistics
    
    $AppLockerArray = @()
    foreach ($App in $AppLockerEvents) {
        
        #Write-Output "Runnign for $App"
        
        # Sanitise file path
        $AppPath = ($([string]$App.FilePath).Replace('%%OSDRIVE%%', "$env:SystemDrive"))
        
        # Check if file still is present and obtain info 
        if (Test-Path -Path $AppPath) {
            # Obtain file and audit log properties
            $AppProperties = Get-ItemProperty -Path $AppPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo
            $AppEventProperties = Get-AppLockerFileInformation -Path $AppPath
            
            # Obtain file hash
            $AppFileHash = Get-FileHash -Path $AppPath -Algorithm SHA256
            
            # Set file properties formatting
            $AppPublisher = $AppEventProperties.Publisher.PublisherName
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($AppPublisher)) {
                $AppPublisher = "Unsigned"
                $AppFullPublisherDetails = "N/A"
            } elseif ($AppPublisher -match "O=") {
                $AppPublisher = $AppEventProperties.Publisher.PublisherName.Split(",")[0]
                $AppPublisher = $AppPublisher.TrimStart("O=")
                $AppFullPublisherDetails = $AppEventProperties.Publisher
            }
            
            $AppFileDescription = $($AppProperties.FileDescription)
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($AppFileDescription)) {
                $AppFileDescription = ($AppPath | Split-Path -Leaf)
            }
            
            $AppProductName = $($AppProperties.ProductName)
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($AppProductName)) {
                $AppProductName = $AppFileDescription
            }
            
            $AppProductVersion = $($AppProperties.FileVersion)
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($AppProductVersion)) {
                $AppProductVersion = "Unavailable"
            }
            
            # Obtain file monitoring count from AppLocker events
            $AppUseStatistics = $AppLockerEvents | Where-Object { $_.FilePath -eq $($App.FilePath) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Counter
            
            $tempapp = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $ComputerName -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ManagedDeviceID" -Value $ManagedDeviceID -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FileDescription" -Value $AppFileDescription -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FileVersion" -Value $AppProductVersion -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ProductName" -Value $AppProductName -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FileHash" -Value $AppFileHash -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value $AppPublisher -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FullPublisherName" -Value $AppFullPublisherDetails -Force
            $tempapp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FileUseCount" -Value $AppUseStatistics -Force
            $AppLockerArray += $tempapp
        }
    }

Within my Log Analystics Workspace, gone to Tables > Create custom log (MMA-based) > Uploaded the Powershell script above > Selected New Line as all of the Timestamps report "Couldn't parse log file. Try selecting a different timestamp format". > And Collection Paths I've added as Windows > C:\Resources\AppLockerEvents.log > Custom Log Name is AppLockerEvents_CL.
Can someone let me know if this is setup correctly? Re the Collection Path, does this need to be a log file that already exists on the endpoint, or is this pushed from the AMA app? Or do you need to run the PS script on the endpoint to output a file? This is the bit that's confusing me.
Many thanks in advance :)
A

Log files do not have a standard format. Post sample of log file.  You need to create a custom parser for the log files.
